# How to get a contract's balance in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, balances

How do I get the balance of a contract with `solidity`?
I know `geth` has `web3.eth.getBalance()`, but that's to get the contract balance after it has been deployed.

Is there a standard way of doing this, or do I have to have a separate var that `uint256` that keeps track of the total balance?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can do this by calling `address.balance`. To get the contract's balance, just do `this.balance`. [Read the docs.](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related)

**Update: As of Solidity ^0.4.24, you need to do:**

```
address(this).balance
```

(Copied from answer by [Paul Berg](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/55300))

Comment: Can i set address(this).balance = 0  in withdraw function to prevent re-enterancy before transfer call. It gives me " Expression has to be an lvalue" on doing so

Comment: You cannot. Balance is not a variable that can be changed on command, it is the amount of Ether the address owns. The only way to set that to zero would be to give away all the Ether. However setting it to zero probably wouldn't prevent reentrancy anyways so you're good

Comment: You cannot do ```address(this).balance = 0 ```, because ```address(this).balance``` is a number not a variable. You can refer to this [clickHere](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol) for  reentrancy  Modifier.

Answer (score 29):

Small update from my side:

[image]

You want to use the following, **address(this).balance;**

Answer (score 22):

As of Solidity ^0.4.24, you need to do:

```
address(this).balance
```

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/contractz/blob/master/contracts/Escrow.sol#L42).

Alternatively, if you need to read the balance of a separate contract:

```
address(contractVar).balance
```

Answer (score 7):

In case of `invalid opcode`, use a local variable of type `address payable` as workaround:

```
        address payable self = address(this);
        uint256 balance = self.balance;
```

In solidity `0.5.14`, I get an `invalid opcode`, debugging showed me, that it is exactly here:

```
address(this).balance
```

Test result:

```
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
     at PromiEvent (node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/promievent.js:6:1)                                                              
      at TruffleContract.destroy (node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/execute.js:158:1)                                                 
      at Context.it (test/1_PactaTest.js:108:17)                                                                                                              
      at web3.eth.getBlockNumber.then.result (node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/testrunner.js:161:1)                              
      at <anonymous>                                                                                                                                          
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Debugging:

```
debug(development:0x7655ecf8...)> 

Pacta.sol:

115:     // move whole balance to the owner
116:     function withdraw() public managers isActive {
117:         uint256 part = address(this).balance / beneficiaries.length;
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        

debug(development:0x7655ecf8...)> 

Transaction halted with a RUNTIME ERROR.

This is likely due to an intentional halting expression, like assert(), require() or revert(). It can also be due to out-of-gas exceptions. Please inspect your transaction parameters and contract code to determine the meaning of this error.
```

Comment: This solution throws an error
`TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.
         address payable self = address(this); `

Comment: use payable(address(this)).balance

Answer (score 1):

`uint256 contractBalance = address(this).balance;`

Answer (score 1):

I think the code should looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Balance {

  function balance() public returns (uint256){
    return payable(address(this)).balance;
  }
}
```

Comment: The cast to payable isn't needed.

Comment: For some reasons, for me, it HAS to be CASTED to payable. the normal address(this).balance didn't work for me. But this payable(address(this)).balance works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple function which accept the address and in return it just return back amount of eth u hold

```
function balance(address owner) public view returns(uint accountBalance)
{
   accountBalance = owner.balance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`address(this)` give address of current deployed smart contract

`<address>.balance` give balance of any address. e.g. `0x9812j3....kh1298n.balance`

to `get balance of contract from contract itself`. use this code:

```
function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
   return address(this).balance;
}
```

to `get balace of any contracts/person of the whole blockchain`, use this code:

```
function getBalance(address ContractAddress) public view returns(uint){
    return ContractAddress.balance;
}
```

ref: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=address%20initial#salted-contract-creations-create2

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is add this two agregators to your function **public** and **view** for show it and access it to every one.

```
//                       |      |
//                       v      v
function showBalance() public view returns(uint) {
   return address(this).balance;
}
```

Regards

Comment: You don't need the cast to `payable`.