# Get contract's balance in js test

Tags: solidity, javascript, mocha

When getting contract's balance on Remix, it returns the correct answer.
But when the same function is called with JS Test, it returns a lot of junk.

I referred to [How to get a contract's balance in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21448/how-to-get-a-contracts-balance-in-solidity) but it does not work anymore or something is missing in my JS code.

Solidity:

```
function contractBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

Javascript:

```
it('should return contracts balance', async function() {
    let contractBalance = await this.auction.contractBalance()
    console.log(contractBalance)
})
```

Output:

```
TruffleConfig {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  _deepCopy: [ 'compilers' ],                                                                                                                                                                                      
  _values: {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    truffle_directory: '/home/satoshi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/lib/node_modules/truffle',                                                                                                                       
    working_directory: '/home/satoshi/auction',                                                                                                                                                    
    network: 'development',                                                                                                                                                                                        
    networks: { development: [Object] },                                                                                                                                                                           
    verboseRpc: false,                                                                                                                                                                                             
    gas: null,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    gasPrice: null,                                                                                                                                                                                                
    from: null,                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    confirmations: 0,                                                                                                                                                                                              
    timeoutBlocks: 0,                                                                                                                                                                                              
    production: false,                                                                                                                                                                                             
    skipDryRun: false,                                                                                                                                                                                             
    build: null,                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    resolver: TestResolver {                                                                                                                                                                                       
      resolver: [TestResolver],                                                                                                                                                                                    
      source: [TestSource],                                                                                                                                                                                        
      search_path: '/tmp/test-202034-9962-wwsk5l.xcbo',                                                                                                                                                            
      seen: [],                                     
      require_cache: {},                            
      cache_on: true                                
    },  
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `await this.auction.contractBalance().call()`.