# How to get ETH supply from smart contract?

Tags: ether, oracles, totalsupply

knowing ETH supply from a contract have a lot of use cases in portfolio management. As far as i know there is no native way to query ETH supply from the contract. Is there any provable and trustless way to have it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a contract's balance in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21448/how-to-get-a-contracts-balance-in-solidity)

Comment: or you mean the total ETH supply available out there?

Comment: if you mean eth total supply, I guess requesting it to a few chainlink data providers would do the trick (quick check on chainlink market: tusd has such feed for instance)

Comment: I'm going to vote to close for now, but consider adding more context to this question and we can reopen. The above linked from minhhn2910 is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

By using this code: `address(this).balance;`

[reference](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related)